# Android Studio, Fragments showing above one another

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Hi I am trying to build a registration screen in Android studio and I am having issues with the layout of my fragments within the screen. I have four xml and java classes that I am working from sorry if its a bit much to read through. I'll also add images so its a bit easier to understand my issue.

activity_driver_registration_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`enter code here`
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/registrationScreenActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E6B725"
tools:context=".AllDriverScreens.RegistrationScreen.DriverRegistrationScreen">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".27"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/driverlogin_tab_background_shape"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".709"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/driverRegistration_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".89"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/driverRegistration_tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/driverRegistration_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_aplashscreen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registrationWelcomeText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee"
    android:text="@string/driver_1st_registration_WelcomeText"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_WelcomeText"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/driver_1st_registration_Slogan"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationWelcomeText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_driver_registration1st_screen_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/registrationFragment1"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationUsername"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_1st_registration_UsernameHint"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="#000"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.120"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationEmail"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_1st_registration_EmailHint"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="#000"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationUsername"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0450"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationPassword"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_1st_registration_PasswordHint"
    android:padding="5dp"`enter code here`
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="15"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationEmail"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0450"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="#000">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registrationNext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button_shape"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/driver_1st_registration_NextButtonText"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.84"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationPassword"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registrationBack"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button_shape"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/driver_1st_registration_LoginButtonText"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_Login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationPassword"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_driver_registration2nd_screen_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/registrationFragment2"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registrationGenderText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_ChooseGenderText"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.095"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.040"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationGenderText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.030"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:onClick="saveRadioButtonData"
        android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_Radio_button_MaleText" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:onClick="saveRadioButtonData"
        android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_Radio_button_FemaleText" />
</RadioGroup>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationFName"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_2nd_registration_FirstNameHint"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000000"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0350"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationLName"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_2nd_registration_LastNameHint"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationFName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0250"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationLName"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.045"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".9" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_SelectAgeText"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".095"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.015"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/regDatePicker"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0250"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registrationNext1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button_shape"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_NextButtonText"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.911"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regDatePicker"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registrationBack1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button_shape"
    android:text="@string/driver_2nd_registration_LoginButtonText"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_Login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regDatePicker"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_driver_registration3rd_screen_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
    android:id="@+id/countryCode"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"
    app:ccp_showFlag="true"
    app:ccp_showFullName="true"
    app:ccp_showNameCode="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.250"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/registrationNumber"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/driver_3rd_registration_PhoneNumberHint"
    app:boxStrokeColor="#000"
    android:textColorHint="#000"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:hintTextColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryCode"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:inputType="phone" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registrationButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_button_shape"
    android:onClick="callOTPScreen"
    android:text="@string/driver_3rd_registration_RegisterButtonText"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:transitionName="transition_registration_Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.250"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registrationNumber"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".85" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below is the code for the java classes

RegistrationActivityAdapater.java

```
public class RegistrationActivityAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context context;
int totalTabs;

public RegistrationActivityAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, Context context, int totalTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            RegistrationFragment1 registrationFragment1 = new RegistrationFragment1();
            return  registrationFragment1;

        case 1:
            RegistrationFragment2 registrationFragment2= new RegistrationFragment2();
            return  registrationFragment2;

        case 3:
            RegistrationFragment3 registrationFragment3 = new RegistrationFragment3();
            return  registrationFragment3;

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

RegistrationFragment1.java

```
public class RegistrationFragment1 extends Fragment {

Button mNext, mBack;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_driver_registration1st_screen_fragment, container, false);
    
    mNext = view.findViewById(R.id.registrationNext);
    mBack = view.findViewById(R.id.registrationBack);

    mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistrationFragment1 fragment1 = new RegistrationFragment1();
            RegistrationFragment2 fragment2 = new RegistrationFragment2();
            RegistrationFragment3 fragment3 = new RegistrationFragment3();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.registrationFragment1, fragment2);
            transaction.hide(fragment1);
            transaction.show(fragment2);
            transaction.hide(fragment3);

            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DriverLoginActivityScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

        return view;
    }
}
```

RegistrationFragment2.java

```
public class RegistrationFragment2 extends Fragment {

Button mNext, mBack;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_driver_registration2nd_screen_fragment, container, false);

    RegistrationFragment1 fragment1 = new RegistrationFragment1();
    RegistrationFragment2 fragment2 = new RegistrationFragment2();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.hide(fragment1);
    ft.show(fragment2);
    ft.commit();

    mNext = view.findViewById(R.id.registrationNext1);
    mBack = view.findViewById(R.id.registrationBack1);

    mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RegistrationFragment1 fragment1 = new RegistrationFragment1();
            RegistrationFragment2 fragment2 = new RegistrationFragment2();
            RegistrationFragment3 fragment3 = new RegistrationFragment3();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.registrationFragment2, fragment3);
            transaction.hide(fragment1);
            transaction.show(fragment2);
            transaction.hide(fragment3);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RegistrationFragment1 fragment1 = new RegistrationFragment1();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.registrationFragment2, fragment1);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

        return view;
    }
}
```

[The first fragment screen which shows where the user can enter their email and other information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glqnC.jpg)

[Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 is duplicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C77G.jpg)

Comment: You're using two different containers here. The `replace` method takes in the ID of the container that you want to put the new fragment, so by specifying different containers, the other one will never get replaced

Comment: Hi thank you for replying to this, could you specify which line exactly

Comment: There's a lot of code here so I can't be sure, but you have `transaction.replace(R.id.registrationFragment1, fragment2);` and `transaction.replace(R.id.registrationFragment2, fragment3);` for example, which are different containers. But if that's not the case, you should produce a [mre] instead of posting all your code. 99% is not relevant and is really hard for us to test.